# tkinterで特定の画像をクリックした時にイベントが起こるようにしたい

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

画像をクリックするとイベントが起こるようにするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか
（tkinterで画像を表示しています。）

a = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="○○.png")
　　canvas.create_image(x,y,image=a)

この表示した画像をクリックしてイベントを発生させたいです。

Comment: この記事が参考になると思われます。[【Python】Tkinker第5回 ウィジェットを使用してマウスイベントを作成](https://shizenkarasuzon.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/02/03/034523)

Comment: ちなみに「この表示した画像をクリックしてイベントを発生させたいです。」という表現だと「Pythonスクリプトのプログラム上からクリックイベントを発生させたい」のか、「画像をマウスでクリックした時に発生するイベントのハンドラを定義・登録してクリックされたら処理を行いたい」のかが曖昧です。あと「特定の画像をクリックした時に」というからには、イベントが起こる画像と起こらない画像の最低2つが例に示されていないと十分では無いでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter のフォトイマジの機能を使用する場合は、画像形式を「GIF、PPM、または PGM」に設定する必要があります。それ以外の場合は、PILLOW を使用してファイルを変換できます。

---

#### tkinter を PhotoImage として使用する

```py
# photoimage
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)

a = tk.PhotoImage("maru-maru.gif") # can use gif, ppm and pgm
canvas.create_image(x, y, a)

root.mainloop()
```

---

#### tkinter と PILLOW を PhotoImage として使用する

```
pip install pillow
```

```py
# Using pillow
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage

import tkinter as tk

...
# Write your code here
a = PhotoImage("maru-maru-file.jpg")
...
```

Comment: この回答はちょっと質問で聞きたいことからは外れている気がします。質問で聞きたいのは画像をクリックしたときのイベント処理に関する物でしょう。それから`.png`は最近のPython/tkinterではサポートされているようですが。[画像](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.html#images), [TkinterはPNGに対応した](https://betashort-lab.com/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/python/tkinter%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/#toc2)

Comment: Then, I will suggest you to use the event binding class, such as the quoted triangular brackets (“<event>”) as bonded to the mouse (“<click>”).